# pymysql: MySQL Parameterized LIKE Query

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql, parameterized-query

Why am I getting `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` when trying to execute this query? I need to be able to append `%{}%` to the IP I am passing in so that i can run a `LIKE` mysql query.

If this isn't the correct way to parameterize a `LIKE` query using the `%` wildcard, how do you do this?

Class:

```
class IpCleaner(object):
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip
        self.iplike = '%{}%'.format(self.ip)

    def lookup(self):
        self.dbconnect()
        select_query = (
            "SELECT `name`,`source`,`destination` FROM mytable "
            "WHERE (`source` LIKE ? OR `destination` ? );"
        )

        params = [self.iplike, self.iplike]
        print params
        self.cur.execute(select_query, params)
        print self.cur.fetchall()
```

Instantiation:

```
a = IpCleaner('74.121.242.2')

a.lookup()
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
['%74.121.242.2%', '%74.121.242.2%']
  File "/home/dobbs/shunlibs/IpCleaner.py", line 87, in <module>
    a.palorulelookup()
  File "/home/dobbs/shunlibs/IpCleaner.py", line 81, in lookup
    self.cur.execute(select_query, params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Not sure about the python code, but it looks like you're missing a `LIKE` after `destination`.

Comment: my bad, i will update that. Also I just discovered it had something to do with using `?` instead of `%s`

Answer (score 0):

use `%s` instead of `?` in the `select_query` variable